# Missing UI Component scripts after downgrading Unity

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have recently downgraded Unity 3D from version 2019.2.0b2 to 2019.1.5f1. But when I opened my scene in the downgraded version, I couldn't find any of the UI elements. On further checking out the UI elements in the scene hierarchy, I noticed that all the scripts attached to the UI elements were missing.

I have tried removing the Library folder and re-imported the packages.

I have tried resetting the packages through Help > Reset Packages to default.

I have also tried deleting the package.json file from Unity UI folder.

None of what I did seems to solve the issue.

Please help me with this. I am really stuck.

Comment: Unity projects are not downgradable! In the newer Version Unity has information about what was changed relative to earlier versions so it automatically applies those changes to your scripts. The other way is not possible ofcourse ... how should the earlier version know what changes will come in future Unity versions? Is there a special reason for the downgrade? In general: Start using **version control**! The most common one is [Git](https://git-scm.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually put the scripts back again to the UI elements. When scripts are lost you can't do anything but put them back again. Take a backup before you degrade unity version. If you had taken backup then put the scripts and use copy component and paste it accordingly for serializable fields.

Comment: In general you shouldn't downgrade at all ... Unity projects are not backwards compatible